# Unity Touch Detection for Jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

Hi guys! I am trying to remove the jump button and replace it with a touch control, however when i tested it, the script would count any touch as a jump. My goal is to make it only detect it when the player touches any part of the screen except the joystick. Does anyone know how i would achieve this goal?
Here is my code:

```
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * Jump);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For ignoring the region of the joystick  you would have to filter the touches rather going through all [`Input.touches`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html) and only keep "valid" ones so those that are

- currently in the [`TouchPhase.Began`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html) phase
- and **not** over your joystick. Assuming an UI element in a `Canvas` you could use [`IsPointerOverGameObject(int)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) passing in the touche's [`fingerId`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html) which returns `true` if the touch is over any UI element.

For making filtering easier you can use [Linq `Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any)

```
if(Input.touches.Any(touch => touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
{
     Rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * Jump);
}
```

using `Any` here is basically just a shortcut for writing

```
foreach(var touch in Input.touches)
{
    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
    {
        Rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * Jump);
        break;
    }
}
```

The condition you can extend and refine according to your needs. You could e.g. also simply ignore all touches in a certain region of the screen by using the `touch.position` like e.g.

```
if(Input.touches.Any(touch => touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began && touch.position.x > MIN_X && touch.position.y > MIN_Y && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
{
     Rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * Jump);
}
```

where in `MIN_X` and `MIN_Y` you define a rectangle that would cover your joystick

Comment: Same thing happens, each time someone moves the joystick it goes off